# How to properly parse this scenario in a simple bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file where each key-value pair takes a new line. There is a possibility of having multiple values for each key. I want to return a list of all pairs that have a "special key", where "special" is is defined as some function.

For Example, if "special" is defined as a key that somewhere has a value of 100

```
A 100
B 400
A hello
B world
C 100
```

I would return

```
A 100
A hello
C 100
```

How to do this in bash?

Comment: what if multiple keys have the value 100, say `C 100`, do you want to return that as well?

Comment: yes, those should be returned as well

Comment: does it have to be `bash` or can it be any unix tool such as `awk`?

Comment: Awk would be fine.. will rephrase the question..

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

special=100    

awk -v s=$special '
{
  a[$1,$2]
  if($2 ~ s)
    k[$1]
}

END
{
  for(key in k)
    for(pair in a)
    {
      split(pair,b,SUBSEP)
        if(b[1] == key)
          print b[1],b[2]
    }
}' ./infile
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ special=100; echo -e "A 100\nB 400\nA hello\nB world\nC 100" | awk -v s=$special '{a[$1,$2];if($2 ~ s)k[$1]}END{for(key in k)for(pair in a){split(pair,b,SUBSEP); if(b[1] == key)print b[1],b[2]}}'
A hello
A 100
C 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
id=`grep "\<$special\>$" yourfile | sed -e "s/$special//"`
[ -z "$id" ] || grep "^$id" yourfile
```

**Returns:**

If `special=100`

```
A 100
A hello
C 100
```

If `special="hello"`

```
A 100
A hello
```

If `special="A"`

```
(nothing)
```

If `special="ello"`

```
(nothing)
```

**Notes**

- drop the `\<\>` if you want partial match
- add `| uniq` at the end if there is a possibility of multiple entrances of the same pair (`A 100`, `A 100`, ...) but you don't want that in your output.

Comment: Wouldn't that fail if a key is named $special?

Comment: @Santiago: well... $special gets expanded first so no.

Comment: Nono, I mean, suppose special=hello, and there's a key named 'hello' (with any other value). $special expands in my comment as well :P

Comment: The problem I see with this is that you will get errorenous keys if the a key contains the *special value* inside it.  For example `Foo200Bar = hello` and the *special value* is `200`

Comment: @Santiago: oic. "$special$" handles that.

Comment: Right, what @Santiago said but its more than being equal to, all it has to do is *contain* the *special value*

Comment: @SiegX, @Santiago: it's not clear if OP wants partial match or not. We can use `\<\>` for exact match.

Answer (score 1):

******* script *************

```
#!/bin/bash

grep " $1" data.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep -f /dev/fd/0 data.txt
```

result:

```
./test.sh 100

A 100
A hello
C 100
```

******* inline ***********

the first grep must contain the 'special' preceded by a space ' ':

```
grep " 100" data.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1 | grep -f /dev/fd/0 data.txt

A 100
A hello
C 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v special="100" '$2==special{a[$1]}($1 in a)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Whew! My bash was incredibly rusty! Hope this helps:

```
FILE=$1
IFS=$'\n' # Internal File Sep, so as to avoid splitting in whitespaces
FIND="100"
KEEP=""

for line in `cat $FILE`; do
    key=`echo $line | cut -d \  -f1`;
    value=`echo $line | cut -d \  -f2`;

    echo "$key = $value"

    if [ "$value" == "$FIND" ]; then
            KEEP="$key $KEEP"
    fi
done

echo "Keys to keep: $KEEP"

# You can now do whatever you want with those keys.
```

Comment: `KEEP="";FIND="100"; while read line; do if [[ "$FIND" == "${line##* }" ]]; then KEEP+="${line%% *} ";fi; done < ./infile; echo "Keys to keep: $KEEP"`. The problem with this is that if you have multiple hits on the same key they will be added to $KEEP, so you could theoretically have `A C A A C C` etc.